# Area of irregular polygon using side edges

Tags: geometry, polygons

I have only lengths for the sides of an irregular polygon, can anyone tell me how I can measure the area of the polygon? Remember only lengths of all the sides , no angles or coordinates.

Few forums mention about trangulation of the polygon etc But I only have side lengths.

Does anybody has any feedback?

Comment: Unless the polygon is a 3-gon, more information is needed.

Answer (score 5):

Imagine building the polygon by joining pieces of wood with hinges. Because the structure is in general not rigid, the answer to your question is indeterminate except if:

(a) One side is longer than the sum of all the other sides - in which case no polygon exists

(b) One side is equal to the sum of all the other sides, in which case the polygon is degenerate of area $0$

(c) Your polygon is a triangle - apply [Heron's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)

[Here](http://www.drking.org.uk/hexagons/misc/polymax.html) is a proof that the polygon has maximum area if all vertices lie on a circle. It also proves that for the maximum area, the order of the sides does not matter.

Comment: See the question in the link for further information http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115338/calculating-the-area-of-an-irregular-polygon

Answer (score 1):

The area of a square with all sides $1$ is greater than the area of a parallelogram with all sides $1$, if the parallelogram is not a square.

Answer (score 0):

Building on coffeemath`s answer i think i should mention this (because he uses the square which is regular polygon and you want to work with irregular ones):

It is true that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists parallelogram with side lengths all equal to $1$ such that its area is less than $\varepsilon$ so at least in the case $n=4$ we need more information then just the side lengths.

Answer (score 0):

There is [work by David Robbins, *et al.*](http://www.haverford.edu/math/lbutler/Heptagon.pdf), on the area of cyclic polygons given the lengths of the sides.