# Maximum surface area of polygons with sequential side lengths.

Tags: geometry, limits, polygons

What is the maximum area of a polygon with sides of lengths $1,2,3,\ldots,N$?

Intuition tells me the polygon must be inscribed in a regular polygon with $1+2+3+ \cdots +N$ sides.

What would be the limit of the surface area of a polygon with $N \to \infty$ if the series converge?

Comment: I remember that solving for marimum area polygon given the side lengths simply means the polygon vertices lie on a circle.

Comment: @SmileyCraft You are correct.  For example, [Maximum Polygon Area](http://www.drking.org.uk/hexagons/misc/polymax.html) states this, along with 2 proofs.

Comment: Also note this question is not apparently a duplicate, but it is quite closely related to, [Area of irregular polygon using side edges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471930/area-of-irregular-polygon-using-side-edges).

Comment: @SmileyCraft:  Perhaps... but in what sequential order?  Ahh... I see that it doesn't matter as the area of the external "caps" for each segment are unchanged.

Comment: Let $A(n)$ denote the maximum are of a polygon with sides of lengths $1,2,3,...,n$ and let $S(n)=1+2+3+...+n=n(n+1)/2$. Then at least we can say $\lim_{n\to\infty}A(n)/(S(n))^2=1/\pi$. This because we approximate area and circumference of a circle.

Comment: Also, regarding order of lengths, note the page I linked to, [Maximum Polygon Area](http://www.drking.org.uk/hexagons/misc/polymax.html), explicitly says "It does not matter in which order the polygon sides occur." Note I see now this has already been resolved, but I'm not allowed to delete this comment, so I'm just leaving it in anyway, just in case somebody may find it helpful.

Comment: The area of the polygon is a sum of Isosceles triangles with equal legs and sequential base lengths. With leg size 1 would it be helpful to define the triangle area using sine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you just need to place the vertices on a circle. So if the radius $r$ is known, then the area is the sum of the areas of a bunch of isosceles triangles with base length $1,2,3,...,n$ and slanted length $r$. So they have height $\sqrt{r^2-1/2},\sqrt{r^2-2/2},...,\sqrt{r^2-n/2}$. So the total area is $1\sqrt{r^2-1/2}+2\sqrt{r^2-2/2}+...+n\sqrt{r^2-n/2}$.

To find the radius $r$ note that the sum of the angles of the isosceles triangles must be $2\pi$. So we have $\sin^{-1}(\frac{1/2}{r})+\sin^{-1}(\frac{2/2}{r})+...+\sin^{-1}(\frac{n/2}{r})=2\pi$. I don't know if there is an analytic or geometric way to solve for $r$, but computationally you can simply do a binary search.

EDIT: By [Brahmagupta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_formula) at least for $n=4$ we can calculate the maximal area is $\sqrt{(s-1)(s-2)(s-3)(s-4)}$ where $s=(1+2+3+4)/2=5$, so the area is $\sqrt{4!}=2\sqrt{6}\approx4.9$.

EDIT2: [Apparently](http://www.mathos.unios.hr/kolokvij/slike/abs_svrtan.pdf) there are formulas like Brahmagupta's for up to $8$ sides. However, more than $8$ sides appears to be a currently unsolved problem. Hence, I expect you will not get a better answer than binary search.

However, as I mentioned in the comments $\lim_{n\to\infty}A(n)/(S(n))^2=1/\pi$, so you can use this to approximate $A(n)$. However, binary search definitely allows more precise approximations.